Help find funny ninja movie (Or was it Chips on TV?)
Some rocket was on an island about to be launched by terrorists to the mainland?
I think there were hostages?
A team of ninja hit the island, American I think, male&female black&white.
One ninja put a puppet of an old man, in a tree by a wall, and threw his voice.
Two "guards" went to the staircase in the wall to look at it, and the puppet said:
"Welcome to top of stairs, you do not often see old man in tree,
it is called DIVERSION, look behind you!"
So the guards turn around and a ninja jumps from the tree nearby and slaps them both in the head with a big stick, or bo staff or whatever.
(sorry, spoiler alert!!)
They find the rocket with a few seconds to spare, but
they are unable to keep it from launching. Female ninja tells male to "use his ki" and he puts a finger inside the nose to pull the warhead out with suction of his index finger????? magnet? static? whatever....
I think it could have been chemical or biological.

A few people have told me it was "American Ninja 2" but, I did not see these scenes when I watched it.

I do remember someone changed the channel during commercial, I tried to turn it back, but could not find it. Chips was on one channel though. I had looked for Chips in relation with Ninja, and found nothing before. Last night I found a link between C.h.i.p.s. + Martial Arts + Rocket. Season 5 Episode 27 "Force Seven", was about a martial arts team, and some scientist who studied rockets. I do not have the Chips DVDs, Amazon prime does not have season 5. Vudu does not have season 5. If anyone with season 5 DVD con confirm the dialogue and scenes I spoke of, I would appreciate it greatly!

A friend had the Episode of Chips on VHS!
It is Season 5, Ep 27 "Force Seven"
The scene in question was around 34m30s.
Thanks to everyone who tried!
